# No correlation in any of my models using linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, non-linear-regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGflF.png)
Hello everyone,

I am currently working on an assignment in which I need to use 'participation' as dependent variable and everything else you see as independent variable. I have attached a pic of the data table.
When i use the regression function lm() - eg lm(participation  ~ gender) - I keep getting R^2=0.

Anyone knows ho to help?
This is my code

```
model1 <- lm(participation ~ education,
             data = data) 
model1
screenreg(model1)
summary(model1)
plot1 <- plot(allEffects(model1))
plot1
```

I think I need to change the variable participation into a continous variable somehow but not sure how!